# Is it possible to check if a url sent to Flask will 404?

Tags: python, flask

I have a list of urls and need to find all the ones that will not go to Flask's 404 not found page.  Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the underlying url map to simulate what would happen if Flask tried to dispatch each url as a request.  This requires that the path, HTTP method (such as GET) and any query args are known and separate.

```
from werkzeug.routing import RequestRedirect, MethodNotAllowed, NotFound

to_test = (
    ('/user/1', 'GET', {}),
    ('/post/my-title/edit', 'POST', {}),
    ('/comments', 'GET', {'spam': 1}),
)
good = []
adapter = app.create_url_adapter(None)

if adapter is None:
    raise Exception('configure a SERVER_NAME for the app')

for path, method, args in to_test:
    try:
        adapter.match(path, method, query_args=args)
    except RequestRedirect:
        pass
    except (MethodNotAllowed, NotFound):
        continue

    good.append((path, method, args))

# good list now contains all tuples that didn't 404 or 405
```

This won't give the whole picture though, as the actual view could raise a 404 (or other error) during processing.  Ultimately, you can't really know if a path is good unless you actually make a request to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `test_client` method of `app` (or `current_app` if you're using blueprints) to create a temporary application context that you can send requests to and get `flask.wrappers.Response` instances back which contain response data, including the `status_code` of the response:

```
with current_app.test_client() as tc:
    resp = tc.get('/url/that/does/not/exist')

>>> resp.status_code
404
```

As such, to find all urls that return a 404 status, I would do:

```
# urls = list of strings containing URLs.

with current_app.test_client() as tc:
    not_found = [u for u in urls if tc.get(u).status_code == 404]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What I try to test if the exact rule is existed in flask app.url_map:

```
"/the/exact/rule/<instance_id>" in [rule.rule for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()]
```

2. When testing the uri can be visited or not:

- open with http connection (Browser, curl, httpie, postman etc)
- using pytest:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    from product.cli import app

    app.add_url_rule('/test/<instid>', 'test',
                     lambda instid: b'test_resp')
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


def test_route_map(client):
    ret = client.get('/test/1')
    assert ret.data == b'test_resp'
```